# In the BBC Planet Earth trailer - where is the sky diver jumping?

Tags: planet-earth

BBC created Planet Earth series a few years ago.

The trailer can be seen [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/collections/p00fxg1n) - if you go to 0.25 (screenshot below) it shows a sky diver jumping into a forest hole - I wanted to know where that is filmed.

[image: screen-bbc-planet-earth-sky-diver]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Cave of Swallows" - This can be seen [here:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocpuuaNwMSw) at about 1:05

From the youtube description:
This 400 meters deep cave is located in a rainforest in San Luis Potosí.
This Video is a beginning of BBC´s 2006 "Planet Earth".